# Vuetify block UI for a few seconds

Tags: vuetify.js

Loading v-for on follow code:

```
  <v-flex class="v-card-cards" xs6 sm4 md4 lg2>
<v-card>
  <v-card-title>
    <span class="headline black--text">
      <v-tooltip bottom>
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
          <v-btn icon color="warning" flat small v-on="on">
            <v-icon>edit</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </template>
        <span>{{ $t('messages.app.edit') }}</span>
      </v-tooltip>
      <v-tooltip bottom>
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
          <v-btn icon color="error" flat small v-on="on">
            <v-icon>delete</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </template>
        <span>{{ $t('messages.app.delete') }}</span>
      </v-tooltip>
    </span>
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-icon class="profile_icon elevation-5 success--text" x-large>account_circle</v-icon>
  </v-card-title>
  <v-divider class="ml-0"></v-divider>
  <v-list>
    <v-list-tile>
      <v-list-tile-action>
        <v-tooltip top>
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <v-icon color="info" small v-on="on">info</v-icon>
          </template>
          <span>{{ $t('messages.forms.newCard.fields.firstname.label') }}</span>
        </v-tooltip>
      </v-list-tile-action>
      <div>
        <span class="caption truncate">{{ item.firstname }}</span>
      </div>
    </v-list-tile>
    <v-divider inset></v-divider>
    <v-list-tile>
      <v-list-tile-action>
        <v-tooltip top>
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <v-icon color="info" small v-on="on">info</v-icon>
          </template>
          <span>{{ $t('messages.forms.newCard.fields.lastname.label') }}</span>
        </v-tooltip>
      </v-list-tile-action>
      <div>
        <span class="caption truncate">{{ item.lastname }}</span>
      </div>
    </v-list-tile>
    <v-divider inset></v-divider>
    <v-list-tile>
      <v-list-tile-action>
        <v-tooltip top>
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <v-icon color="info" small v-on="on">people</v-icon>
          </template>
          <span>{{ $t('messages.forms.newCard.fields.groups.label') }}</span>
        </v-tooltip>
      </v-list-tile-action>
      <div>
        <span
          v-for="group in item.groups"
          :key="item.groups._id"
          class="caption truncate"
        >{{ group.description }}</span>
      </div>
    </v-list-tile>
    <v-divider inset></v-divider>
    <v-list-tile>
      <v-list-tile-action>
        <v-tooltip top>
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <v-icon color="info" small v-on="on">note</v-icon>
          </template>
          <span>{{ $t('messages.forms.newCard.fields.notes.label') }}</span>
        </v-tooltip>
      </v-list-tile-action>
      <div>
        <span class="caption truncate">{{ item.notes }}</span>
      </div>
    </v-list-tile>
    <v-divider inset></v-divider>
  </v-list>
  <v-card-actions class="mx-3">
    <v-spacer></v-spacer>
    <v-tooltip top>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
        <v-badge overlap color="info">
          <template v-slot:badge>12</template>
          <v-icon
            large
            v-on="on"
            color="grey darken-1"
            @click="$router.push({ name: 'dashboard' })"
          >description</v-icon>
        </v-badge>
      </template>
      <span>{{ $t('messages.forms.newCard.fields.notes.label') }}</span>
    </v-tooltip>
  </v-card-actions>
</v-card>
```

page is blocked for a few seconds, during the loading of this contents. Why? Can resolve? I have tried avoid 'v-' directive of vuetify, using only html and so not get nothing block. But i want use vuetify style.

Have tried to find other similar question on web but i don't find nothing about this argument

Comment: Try taking out small pieces to find out what part slows it down.
The 2 uses of v-slot:activator and the code within them stand out to me as unusual markup.

Comment: Probably too many components. Try to utilize [vue-virtual-scroller](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller) if possible. I had similar problems so solved it on codepen (notice v-if on v-menu in faster version) - [Slower version](https://codepen.io/traxo/pen/OYpEPO), and [Faster version](https://codepen.io/traxo/pen/yZWPvN). Not sure if depends on machine but you should notice the difference between the codepens. Not easy to debug cuz you gotta test component by component, and also parent components maybe, which you have not included in the snippet.

Comment: i tried many combinations. But no have signifiers result. Exist solution for render before v- vuetify components?